# Differentiation operator and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V = \{p(x) \in F[x] \ | \ \deg(p(x)) \le n\}$. Let $T : V \to V$ be given by differentiation, in essence $$T(p(x)) = p'(x)$$
It seems to me that the only eigenvalue that can exist is $\lambda =0$, since the given operator lowers the degree of any given polynomial and hence makes it impossible for a constant multiple of a polynomial to be equal to the polynomial's derivative. Is my claim correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, correct. In the basis $(x^n,nx^{n-1},n(n-1)x^{n-2},..,n!)$ the matrix of $T$ is in Jordan normal form, having only $0$ in the diagonal (nilpotent):
$$\pmatrix{0 & 0&0&\dots&0\\1&0&0&\dots&0\\0&1&0&\dots&0\\ \vdots &&\ddots &\ddots \\0&0&\dots&1&0}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.  You might also note that (in a larger space of functions) the only solutions of $f'(x) = \lambda f(x)$ are the scalar multiples of $e^{\lambda x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Tp = \lambda p$. Suppose $\lambda \neq 0$ and $p \neq 0$. If $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k x^k$, then $Tp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1) p_{k+1} x^k$. Equating gives $\lambda p_n = 0$, $(k+1)p_{k+1} = \lambda p_k$ for $k = 0,...,n-1$. Hence $p_n = 0$, and then it follows that $p_k = 0$, for $k = 0,...,n-1$, a contradiction. So, if there is an eigenvalue, it must be $0$.

Letting $p(x) = 1$ gives $Tp = 0.p$, hence $0$ is an eigenvalue, and so is **the** eigenvalue.